# Yesod Hardcoded Auth with database access

Tags: sqlite, haskell, authentication, yesod, haskell-persistent

I implemented a Yesod auth system like described [here](https://ilikewhenit.works/blog/4), which works fine by looking up username and passwords hardcoded in a list.

I now try to modify this behavior to lookup usernames and passwords in the database by modifying the *lookupUser* and *validPassword* functions. For starters, only *lookupUser*:

```
lookupUser :: Text -> Maybe Owner
lookupUser username = do 
    x <- runSqlite "db.sqlite3" . asSqlBackendReader $ selectFirst [ElementOwnerId ==. username] []
    case x of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just (Entity k v) -> Just $ Owner username (elementOwnerPw v)

asSqlBackendReader :: ReaderT SqlBackend m a -> ReaderT SqlBackend m a
asSqlBackendReader = id
```

But I get the following error which I do not understand:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe’ with ‘IO’
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘MonadBaseControl IO Maybe’
            arising from a use of ‘runSqlite’
          instance ‘MonadBaseControl Maybe Maybe’ at <no location info>
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘runSqlite "db.sqlite3"’
      In the expression: runSqlite "db.sqlite3" . asSqlBackendReader
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        x <- runSqlite "db.sqlite3" . asSqlBackendReader
               $ selectFirst [ElementOwnerId ==. username] []
    |
238 |     x <- runSqlite "db.sqlite3" . asSqlBackendReader $ selectFirst [ElementOwnerId ==. username] []
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Signatures of *runSqlite* and *selectFirst*:

```
runSqlite :: MonadCatchIO m => SqliteReader m a -> Pool Connection -> m a

selectFirst :: (PersistEntity val, PersistEntityBackend val ~ b) => [Filter val] -> [SelectOpt val] -> b m (Maybe (Entity val))
```

Comment: Seems the `do` block inside `lookupUser` is running inside of `Maybe` but `runSqlite` returns something in `IO`. Not sure *how*, but you'll need to deal with that IO somehow. You can see that your `do` is in `Maybe` because of the return type of that function.

Comment: I am generally a bit confused about monads, I added the type signatures of runSqlite and selectFirst in my post. I don't understand where that IO is coming from and why the compiler tells me about a double Maybe.

Comment: Would you mind adding the code where you call lookupUser? Like the function and it's type

Comment: You can see it here: https://ilikewhenit.works/blog/4 I didn't alter the code from this tutorial except naming.

Comment: `runSqlite "db.sqlite3" ...` has type `IO X` for some `X` but you are claiming it has type `Maybe X` due to the type signature you've given to `lookupUser`. This seems pretty clear to me ("Couldn't match type ‘Maybe’ with ‘IO’"). I'm guessing you want `Text -> IO (Maybe Owner)` or maybe even `Text -> MaybeT IO Owner` (but if you don't understand this latter type, don't use it).

Comment: @user2407038 but removing the type signature doesn't change anything about the error message. Can you tell me what to change to get `Text -> Maybe Owner`?

Comment: @Benjoyo You can't get this type. `runSqlite` performs IO (which is reflected in its type) but the type `Text -> Maybe Owner` promises to be a pure function. Perhaps you should elaborate why you feel this function should have precisely the type `Text -> Maybe Owner`.

Comment: @user2407038 because this is the way it is embedded in the auth code in the article I posted above. I need some way to replace this purely functional default behavior with a database access.

Comment: @Benjoyo Your function is used in e.g. [`authenticate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.21/docs/Yesod-Auth.html#t:YesodAuth). If you look at the type of `authenticate` you'll find you can do IO inside of it; therefore there is no barrier to calling a function of type `Text -> IO (Maybe Owner)` from `authenticate`.

Comment: @user2407038 thank you very much, this got me on the right path!